# Purpose of ; and // Special Symbol in LLVM file check tool

Tags: pattern-matching, llvm

I am working with LLVM file check tool.
It has below 3 syntaxes to pattern matching...

1. ; CHECK
2. // CHECK
3. CHECK

I want to know the difference and uses between all above 3 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These aren't special symbols, these are just comment blocks.

`llvm-lit` checks are inserted into comments so that you can contain both test instructions and the code being tested in a single file.

Comment: But There is some difference between them as if that only comments then they should use only 1 kind of syntax and I am observing all of them in syntax.

Comment: It depends on the file type, obviously. C/C++ sources use `//` for comments and LLVM IR sources use `;`.

Comment: can you please add the same information into Answer itself. and also can you please explain a little bit more about it?